# Power BI how to hide default page tabs and get list of available pages for a report

Tags: javascript, powerbi, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-custom-visuals

I am trying to implement some custom page navigation per report in Power BI. I am trying to get a list of the pages for the report so I can loop through those pages in custom tabs of mine. `report.getPages().then(pages => { console.log("in the getpages .then"); console.log(pages)return pages; });`

This is my code and I'm not sure why, once the promise resolves, I'm not able to log the pages. Any help on this is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I just tested this functionality using the [Power BI Embedded Playground](https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-JavaScript/demo/v2-demo/index.html#) -> Sample Report, which is a great way to test SDK functions.

The following snippet is functional and provided by the Power BI Embedded Playground.

```js
// Get a reference to the embedded report HTML element
var embedContainer = $('#embedContainer')[0];
 
// Get a reference to the embedded report.
report = powerbi.get(embedContainer);
 
// Retrieve the page collection and loop through to collect the
// page name and display name of each page and display the value.
report.getPages()
    .then(function (pages) {
        var log = "Report pages:";
        pages.forEach(function (page) {
            log += "\n" + page.name + " - " + page.displayName;
        });
        Log.logText(log);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        Log.log(error);
    });
```

```
> Loaded
> Report pages:
> ReportSectioneb8c865100f8508cc533 - Tiles
ReportSection600dd9293d71ade01765 - Market Share
ReportSectiona271643cba2213c935be - YTD Category
ReportSection1c45b5dc6513ae89b4e3 - Sentiment
ReportSection2ff5a27ac612830bbd93 - Tooltip
ReportSection6da8317ad6cbcae5b3bb - Empty Page
> Rendered
```